# XCode: Can't checkout other branches "Authentication failed"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, grpc

I am having a weird issue on Xcode (version 9.2) where when I try to checkout a different branch, either on my origin or even locally, I get the following error:

> **Authentication failed because the authentication credentials were rejected.**
>   Verify the authentication credentials were entered correctly and try again.

The weird thing is I can pull and push my code with no problems.

I have googled this problem, and there seems to be nothing relevant on SO, and the answers on Apple Forums don't address my problem.

I tried doing this directly from the terminal, but I get an error saying:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
>       Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/FirebaseAuth.framework/Headers/FIRAuthSwiftNameSupport.h
>
> ...
>
> Please move or remove them before you switch branches.

(I have added these files and committed through the terminal as well, to which I get an error that says: Untracked files, nothing added to commit but untracked files present)

Any ideas on how I can start to understand/resolve this?

UPDATE:

I commented out the following pods, and at least I could checkout a different branch!

pod 'Firebase/Core'

pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

pod 'Firebase/Storage'